# Getting Tomorrow's (New Years Day) Timestamp fails with day is out of range for month

Tags: python, timestamp

I am trying to get the timestamp for tomorrow. This has been working for a few days then today (New Year's Eve) it fails with the error message

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/Tomean/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/Scripts/testtime.py",
> line 19, in 
> print("Timestamp_Tomorrow: ", int(datetime(today.year, today.month, today.day + 1, 0 , 0, 0).timestamp())) ValueError: day is
> out of range for month

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
study_timezone = timezone('Europe/London')
today = study_timezone.localize(datetime.now())
print("today",today)
print("Timestamp_Tomorrow: ", int(datetime(today.year, today.month, today.day + 1, 0 , 0, 0).timestamp()))
```

How do I sort out this issue? Is it because it happens to be a new year tomorrow or would it of done this on the last day of every month?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error `ValueError: day is out of range for month` because the last line suggests `int(datetime(today.year, today.month, today.day + 1, 0 , 0, 0).timestamp()))` so `today.day + 1` will be `31+1 =32`, (not January 1st) which is not a valid date.
for your desirable output you need to use `timedelta`, for more specific `tomorrow = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)`.
Your final code will be:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pytz import timezone
study_timezone = timezone('Europe/London')
today = study_timezone.localize(datetime.now())
tomorrow = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)

print("today",today)
print("Timestamp_Tomorrow: ", int(datetime(tomorrow.year, tomorrow.month, tomorrow.day, 0, 0, 0).timestamp()))
```

Note: you need to use `tomorrow.` instead of `today.` method.

Comment: Thanks, works great though I did have to change the tomorrow = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1) to tomorrow = today + timedelta(days=1) so I could also use custom dates when generating the initial date. Thanks, you help alot